# Deconfiguration of images by applying length and height to them

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to present 3 images within 3 divs. I'm working on the server side, so I use HTML string. I'm using ajax to communicate from server to web page. Then I use append to a div, in the web page to display the image.

Everything works fine until I apply the size that the image has to have.

My code for one image:

```
 $html_2 = "<div class=\"box--test-item\"";
    $html_2 = $html_2."<img class=\"main-img\" src=\"data/photos/datateste_".$idtest."/photo.jpg\" alt=\"test\" style= \"{height: 280px; width: 180px;}\">";
    //Html string with information about the image.
    $html_2 =  $html_2."</div>";
```

In my error console:

> element {
>       {
>        **height: 280px;**
>        width: 100px;
>        **}: ;**

The part underlined is error (invalid property value).

The visual bug it's related to the height of the image.

Comment: can you show the visual bug with a screenshot?

Comment: no curly braces in inline styles. Alternatively use the width and height attributes of image rather than as a style

Comment: Remove curly braces as @RamRaider suggested.

Comment: Don't give the curly braces `style="height: 280px; width: 280px;"` should be good

Comment: @RamRaider I tried it that way, but the image was not formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working as @Nikhil Nanjappa said.

Comment: Please accept an answer to help others or I can post one if you want or I can add a note to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa Yes please post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using HTML string, the inline `style` attribute need not have curly braces `{}`.

Instead just `style="height: 280px; width: 180px;"` should work.

No change in rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

php code here

```
 <?php
      $html_2 = '<div class="box--test-item">';
      $html_2 .= '<img class="main-img" src="data/photos/datateste_"'.$idtest.'"/photo.jpg" alt="test" style="height: 280px; width: 180px;">';
      //Html string with information about the image.
       $html_2 .= '</div>';
  ?>
```